# How to put all words from DataFrame in Normal form

Tags: python, pandas

I need to put all words from one column of DataFrame in normal form (by pymorphy2) ?

For example i have :

`First  Sec
My  Я вчера видел цветы красных цветов`

after it i need to get :

`First  Sec
My  я вчера видеть цвета красных цветок`

Comment: For thos of us who don't know the kirilic alphabet: What do you want to do? What did you do so far? Why does this have a pandas tag?

Comment: For one word i use `morph.parse(word)[0].normal_form` . So here i need to split all sentence in DF (pandas) , put all words in normal form and after collect sentence again.

Comment: I don't know how fast this would be but write a function that takes takes a string then use `str.split()` to split apart then apply the `normal_form` then do a `' '.join()` to bring the sentence back together. Then `pd.apply()` the function along your column?

Comment: yeah, can you write it ?

Comment: you should try yourself to be honest that way you will learn more :)

Comment: oh(( so hard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following and let me know how you get on.

By the way I don't know how to use pymorphy2 and the documnetation is in Russian which I don't speak so you may need to adjust that line.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymorphy2

data = pd.read_excel(r'your_file.xlsx')

def converter(sentence):
    list = []
    words = sentence.split()
    for item in words:
        list.append(pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer().parse(item)[0].word)
    return ' '.join(list)

data['column_to_convert'] = data['column_to_convert'].apply(converter)
```

Comment: Thank you, it is gteat, but `list.append(pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer().parse(item)[0].normal_form)` not `word`